# Stick TableHeader Image always on top of the Screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I created a sample app here: https://github.com/steffimueller/LTNavigationBar-TestProject

When you pull down the table at the top above the image a white background appears. This should not be the case. The header image should always be bound at the top of the screen. Here is how it looks in my case:

[image]

and here is how it should look like:

[image]

The former screenshot is from [this app](https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar) using the `parallax` branch of the git repo. It is the first tab in the parallax demo which has the effect I want.

Here is the code I use to create the table:

```
class Page1ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var topView:UIView!
  var topImageView: UIImageView? 

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "sdfsdf"), animated: true)

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIndentifier)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.lt_setBackgroundColor(UIColor.clearColor())

    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

    topView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 212))
    topView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    topView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    topView.clipsToBounds = true

    tableView.tableHeaderView = topView

    let img = UIImage(named: "bg")
    topImageView = UIImageView(image: img)
    topImageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, -89, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 307)
    topImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    topView.addSubview(topImageView!)
  }


  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)
    let offsetY:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offsetY > NAVBAR_CHANGE_POINT {
      let alpha:CGFloat = 1 - ((NAVBAR_CHANGE_POINT + 64 - offsetY) / 64)
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.lt_setBackgroundColor(color.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha))
    }
    else {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.lt_setBackgroundColor(color.colorWithAlphaComponent(0))
    }

    if offsetY < 0 {
      let progress:CGFloat = fabs(offsetY) / 300
      self.topImageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1 + progress, 1 + progress)

    }
  }


  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    tableView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
      make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(-64)
    }

  }
}
```

Edit: I don't want to set `tableView.bounces = false`.

**How can I stick the TableHeader Image always on top of the Screen like in my second screenshot?**

Comment: Have you tried setting your `UITableView` frame?

Comment: as dave buttons answer shows, this question is not clear enough.

Comment: «*I want to rebuild this: https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar without a Storyboard.*» There is nothing in the code that makes you use storyboards.

Comment: @vikingosegundo The problem is that the sample code works with storyboard and my code uses interface builder but get different results.

Comment: @stephan1001, actually its hard to find out what you expect. original code and the code that you develop it seems like same. just different is you code have starching effect on HeaderView. can you please elaborate what the functionality you want ?

Comment: @None I want the same as the ``parallax`` branch in https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar does. The only thing which is left is the following. When you pull down the table at the top above the image a white background appears. This should not be the case. The header image should always be bound at the tom of the screen.

Comment: @None I updated my question completely hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the following in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
topView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300))

let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
tableView.tableHeaderView = testView

let img = UIImage(named: "bg")
topImageView = UIImageView(image: img)

topImageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)
topView.addSubview(topImageView!)
topImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
tableView.addSubview(topView!)
tableView.sendSubviewToBack(topView!)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this.

Do you want the topView to scroll with the table view? If so, instead of adding the topView as a subview, just assign it to the table view's tableHeaderView property.

Don't want it to scroll? Add the topView to the view controller's view, not the table view. Then position the table view below the top view in the nib/storyboard.

Want the table view to scroll over the image view as the user scrolls down? Put the image view behind the table view, make the table view transparent, and make the table view's contentInset start the first cell below the image.

I'm guessing just messing with the contentInset's top value will get you what you want here.

It's not clear why both the topView and the topImageView are needed. It looks like just the topImageView would be sufficient.

Comment: I want to do it like here: https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar but instead doing it in code.

Comment: Then I'd go with using the tableHeaderView property. But what do you mean by "doing it in code"? If you're trying to avoid using Interface Builder, you're headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes I want to avoid using interface builder. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Once learned, Interface Builder is a faster way to develop interfaces. It makes it easier for other developers to understand how your code works. It's how Apple recommends designing your interface. It provides an easier way to work with auto-layout. Your code will be cleaner and easier to maintain. Unlike other IDE interface tools, it doesn't suck. If you can't use it you'll be lacking a skill set required by many iOS development teams. Nearly all books, tutorials, and advice will assume you're going to use Interface Builder.

Comment: The question is how can I solve my problem without it?

Comment: There's nothing in my answer above, or anyone else's answer here, that requires Interface Builder. And anything you see in that code from GitHub that does do what you want can be done in code without Interface Builder.

Comment: I use InterfaceBuild but I don't use the Storyboard and so far I cannot rebuild what I want in a nib. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topView?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a frame to your tableView like this:

```
self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, YYY, 320, 307)
```

where YYY is the Y position you want the table to be positioned at

**UPDATE:**

Based on your updated question, if you want to have the image appear to be "stuck' to the top of the `tableview`, even when the user pulls the table down, you need to use the `bounds` of the `tableView` to set the `frame` of your image.  Use something like this to set the image frame:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 100.0f+self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];

[self.tableView addSubview:myImage];
```

You need to make sure your image is larger then the visible headerView so it will continue to show as the user pulls the table down.

> The "100.0f+" part is just adding height to the image so it will show
>   into the headerView, adjust this to fit your image and tableView
>   header.

**UPDATE 2**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView.delegate=self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource=self;

    UIImageView *myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.myTableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 300.0F+self.myTableView.bounds.size.height)];
    [myImageView setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];


    [self.myTableView addSubview:myImageView];

}
```

Comment: I did this in viewDidLoad and it did not change anything

Comment: why are you doing this? `tableView.addSubview(topView)` ?  Do you want the image to be the header for the table or it's own view? If you want it to be the header then you need to be using  `setTableHeaderView` instead.

Comment: I want to do it like here: https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar but not using interface builder.

Comment: That's custom functionality, why don't you just use their code then?

Comment: I will do it without UIBuilder

Comment: That doesn't matter, just import them and use it.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your updated question

Comment: @mp Could you please update my project: https://github.com/steffimueller/LTNavigationBar-TestProject I still stuck with your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @mp I still don't get your solution. IF you could fix it in my code I will accept immediately and give you the bounty.

Comment: @stephan1001 sorry I don't have time to update your project for you. You should be able to get it working with a little effort.  Start by editing your line of code  `topView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 212))` to use the `CGRectMake` example in my answer.

Comment: I did the update but I got the same effect. Could you please make you answer a little bit more detailed. I am new in this topic. Thank you for help.

Comment: Here is a sample that works. You will need to do the rest yourself. - '(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.myTableView.delegate=self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource=self;
    
    UIImageView *myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.myTableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 300.0F+self.myTableView.bounds.size.height)];
    [myImageView setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
    
    
    [self.myTableView addSubview:myImageView];
    
}'

Comment: I tried this but now the image is over the first 5 rows of the table. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote in my answer? I have highlighted it so you can see it. You need to do some work on your own to make it fit what you need. Whatever your have set your headerView height to, needs to be accounted for in the code I posted.

Comment: Just used @rmp code and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding an ImageView just below the UITableView(background color should be clearColor) and setting the

```
yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bound the UIImage to top of the screen then do the following things. Disable `Bounce` property of `UITableView`. you can disable that property from xib or programmatically as well. here i write the code for disable `Bounce` property programmatically in swift.

```
self.tableView.bounces = false
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @stephan1001, let me know if you want different. whatever you edit your requirement, i am understand that you want to fix your header on top of screen so i will provide this solution

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want to have the bounce but still have the image sticked to the top of the screen. Just try the ``parallax``branch here: https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar and you see what I mean.

Comment: @stephan1001, so you want starching effect once user pull down the UITableView. because once there is bounce flag is enable and UIView is added in UITableViewHeader then defiantly background is showing.

Comment: @stephan1001, you can just hide white background by providing starching effect. that already work in your TestProject.

Comment: @None Please have a look at  the parallaxbranch here: github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar When The user pull down the table there is no white background at the to. The image is alway bound to the top.

Comment: @stephan1001, i have not see that things in `LTNavigationBar` demo as you want. kindly guide me if i wrong

Comment: @None The LTNavigationBar demo helps a lot if you try it out.

Comment: @stephan1001, actually i am not able to find that the `UIImage` is stick at top of screen in `LTNavigationBar ` sample code.

Comment: Please run the dem than you see the effect I showed in the second screen shot. May be I use a wrong word for that. If you run the demo you see that no white background appears at the top when pulling down.

Comment: @stephan1001, in which tab? there is two tab "Demo" on screen. which screen have functionality that you want ?

Comment: The first tab! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What i did in my case is to use tableHeaderView instead of section header like, `myTableView.tableHeaderView = myImageView`
and then in scrollViewDidScrollMethod,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0
        {
        scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
            var headerFrame = myTableView.tableHeaderView?.frame
            headerFrame?.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            headerFrame?.size.height = headerHeight-scrollView.contentOffset.y //headerHeight is a constant for actual height of header on storyboard
            myTableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = headerFrame!

        }

    }
```

Hope this helps in your case